# CF and PDF in secure environment

Tags: security, pdf, coldfusion

I'm using CF9. My problem pertains to an admin application that sets session variables at login to identify the user and user permissions. Depending on the user level, certain pages are allowed for viewing and other pages are not allowed. (I'll refer to this as my 'security framework'. This is wrapped around everything in the root.)

This security framework consists of a `cfif` statement at the top of the CFM page and a closing `cfelse` and `(</)cfif` at the bottom of the page. Everything between this opening `cfif` and closing `cfif` displays if the user has that level permission - standard stuff.

Certain users can upload PDF files, no problem here. PDF files are uploaded to a folder outside of the root and then moved and renamed to folders inside the root.

When uploading, the user chooses categories and subcategories etc. and these variables are inserted in a SQL database during the upload process. Therefore, I have filePaths and fileNames, etc. to set up dynamic links on a page for a user to click and load the PDF (password protected) in the browser.

I have the dynamic link pointing to a `ShowThisPDF.cfm?` with URL variables `filePath= #filePath# & fileName = #fileName#`. I've set up the `ShowThisPDF.cfm` with the security framework at the top and bottom of the page and am trying to copy the uploaded PDF into this page so that the PDF will display in the browser.

I've tried many ways to do this with `cfdocument` and `cfpdf` and `cfcontent`, etc. When I read the error that this is throwing, it does look like it is reaching the uploaded file but I get an "access denied" every time, due to the security framework I suppose.

On a side note, elsewhere in this application I can create a PDF from my cf pages with `cfdocument` with the security framework wrapped around the page and this works perfectly - displaying the PDF in the browser. My problem is in loading an existing PDF into a CFM page that has the security framework - which should allow the PDF to load.

Anyone have an idea as to how I can accomplish the above? I hate to try and bypass my security and it seems logical to "copy" the uploaded PDF into a CFM page that wraps the PDF in the security framework and then display the PDF in the browser.

Comment: Does ColdFusion have permission to view files in these directories?

Comment: Is the "access denied" error that you are receiving your error message or is it being thrown by ColdFusion?  It may not be your security framework at all if ColdFusion cannot access the PDF file in it's current location.

Comment: I think you guys are pointing me in the right direction. After I login (as a user) and I type a direct link to the pdf file in the browser address bar, I get a popup username/password from the server. I'm in a sharded hosting environment. (I don't have administrator rights to the server but I can set folder permissions). Maybe this is it, huh? - ed

Comment: so you type `http://yourdomain.com/ShowThisPDF.cfm?filePath=someFile&fileName=somefilename` and you get prompted for a password, or are you trying to go to `http://yourdomain.com/mypdf.pdf` and getting the prompt?

Comment: Just remember that your ColdFusion security code only governs what web pages your users can see.  When it comes to accessing the file system, it's the OS security at play and the user is ColdFusion.

Comment: I thank all of you for answering...

Comment: Whoops... Travis, I've tried both urls. But yes, the http://yourdomain.com/mypdf.pdf gets the popup username/password from the server. I'm going through the server admin right now, setting user permissions to Read on all folder and subfolders that these PDFs reside in -- it's just taking a while for the server to change the settings. I'll post back here when the server updates. I should be able to just type in the http://yourdomain.com/mypdf.pdf url and have the pdf open (as a test). - ed

Comment: So far with the information provided, I'm guessing that either 1) showThisPDF.cfm is building a bad path to the file or 2) the PDF is picking up some nasty permissions. Try uploading the document somewhere in your webroot instead of below it.

Comment: I can't tell from question whether the _reading_ of PDFs is security restricted or not. If so, then make sure that users cannot circumvent your cfm security system by just visiting the PDF file directly - especially if they have easily guessable names.

Comment: Travis, Thanks. The server is still updating to 'read access' the folders. It said it may take a while - there's a lot of folders and subfolders here. I suspect it is the permissions settings on the server tho (intermedia dotnet). These folders and subfolders are dynamically created (createDirectory) when a user is entered in the system. I'll also try your suggestion of uploading a pdf in the webroot instead of below it, after everything updates on the server. I'll be sure and post back here when things are figured out, but, thanks to y'all, I think I'm on the right path now... - ed

Comment: Thanks, halfer. Once I figure that the user permissions on the server is the culprit, I'll go back to the cfdocument and/or cfpdf to build the pdf with my security framework wrapped around. I'll be setting a userpassword on the pdf itself as well... Good point.

Comment: ahhh. Now I'm getting somewhere... After allowing 'read' access on the server end, I type in a direct url to a pdf and at least now am getting somewhat of a pdf... It prompts for a password and, after typing this in I get a blank pdf that has a checkbox checked in red - no pdf yet but I feel I'm getting somewhere now... - ed

Comment: Thanks to all of you who responded. I've not fixed my problem yet but I'm headed in the right direction per everyone's advice. Apparently there's an issue when these folders are created "on the fly" when a user is set up and I need to re-think how this can be done with the server side automatically setting the 'read' permissions. I may need to re-think my upload section now, but, thanks to everyones's help here I believe my question posted here has been answered... Thanks again. - ed

Comment: Sure will. Thanks, Travis

Comment: I finally determined it's my own security framework that doesn't allow me to open the existing pdf. The error I get when I go directly to the pdf in the url is: "You are not allowed to view this page. The url you attempted to reach has an ISAPI or CGI application installed that verifies user credentials before proceeding. This application cannot verify your credentials." The only thing I can think of to do now is put the pdf in a folder outside of my security, cfpdf this pdf with encryption and a userpassword and hope that's enough security on it. This is really sensitive data here. - ed

Comment: Got this working and will post a gist of the code here if I knew how since comment charactors here has a limit. The only problem I have now is in the cfpdf serving filepath to the cfcontent that allows the pdf to display in browser -- both browser and download filename shows the whole http address. Is there a way to obfiscate the url or change the url/filename without having to make a second copy of the pdf? The pdf opens within my security framework -- all works well except for this one last detail of the filepath showing in filename... -ed

Comment: I figured out the previous comment on url/filename: Instead of using cfpdf and cfcontent (toBinary) - Since the file is on the server I just used a cflocation to call the pdf. I have a password assigned to the pdf. As per above (my) comment, I'd be glad to post the gist of this particular application process if someone can direct me as to how to show the code here, outside of this limited charactor comment box. @Travis, how do I "accept" this post to show this post is resolved for me. Thanks again to all... - ed

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Dan - I had similar issue.  So I ended up doing https: with a windows login and also a ColdFusion Login to Web Application.  At end of day - they need 2 logins to get into the system - then they can see the pdf files etc or what they need.